# Odor proofing floor

Tags: flooring, odors

I have a problem with the downstairs flat and cigarette smoke faintly coming up through the floor. Its pretty nasty, we have had a word and its got better but there is still a faint smell.

We have laminate with underlay at present with wood beading around the edge. Underneath the laminate is just sheets of chipboard.

To remedy the problem. I was thinking of taking the floor up and installing a polythene barrier across the whole floor.

Could anyone please let me know if this is a silly idea or any other ideas for odor proofing the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have forced air heating?

If so, the smell is likely coming through the duct work. I can almost assure you that in such a system, the vents/duct work are not well sealed. So this would allow their system to push smoke into small holes between the floors, and your system to pull the smoke into you place.

Get a HEPA like filter for the furnace.

Put better weather stripping around your doors and windows.

The other thing is to make seal your place as well as possible. Fireblock foam behind electrical outlets, switches and cable, and ductwork faceplates.

Caulk or foam anywhere the water goes through a wall, and the inside edges of your kitchen cabinets, and all the edge of the moulding on where the floor meets the walls, both on the top and bottom of the moulding.

---

As a last resort, loud music or sex might get them to understand just how poorly the building is insulated between the floors.